Trying to find a crocodile movie
I saw a movie on TV around 6-7 years ago. 
It was crocodile movie. 
The main characters were a Doctor, his teenage daughter and his girlfriend who was a forest ranger( I think). The doctor and his daughter go to a forest type area for some research and there they meet the forest ranger who becomes the doctor's girlfriend.
Towards the climax of the movie the daughter gets kidnapped by some smugglers and is tied to a pole. The girlfriend finds her but one of the smugglers sees her and sneaks behind her. 
The daughter tries to alert her but the goon knocks the girlfriend out with an oar. The doctor finds them and says "how dare you hit my girlfriend", then beats the smugglers. 
The place is then attacked by crocodiles but the 3 of them manage to escape in a car.
It was a bit comical movie, not too serious type.

We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing?   Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

I was going to say it was one of the Lake Placid movies, they almost but not quite fit. Then I thought, maybe Primeval? That almost fits - the bad guys are training crocs. In the end, I don't think it's any of them, have you checked out this resource: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_natural_horror_films#Alligators_and_crocodiles

Bits of this remind me of Crocodile Dundee
